# how to find phtml file from url in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am not able to find order phtml file. I want to modify currency in bellow url:

> https://moreideas.ae/magento19/index.php/moreideassupport/index/index/order/MI100010756/mail/ajay.kumar@minerva.in/

Answer (score 0):

Login to Admin Panel
System->Configuration->Developer->Advanced->Debug->Template Path Hints => YES
Clear Cache !!!